# HTML5, CSS3 reference

Tags: html, css

I am searching for an in-depth comprehensive Textbook for learning HTML5
and another book for CSS3 or a a book for both in one , I searched amazon 
and found plenty of results but I don't know which one is comprehensive and 
in-depth Explaining all Details and all about HTML .

note : I have seen the post Learn HTML5 and CSS3 but i don't like websites resources 
I want text books.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start to get the basics is to read **[Dive Into HTML5](https://diveintohtml5.info/)** by Mark Pilgrim. You can even try before you buy because it's free. Another suggestion is **[Pro HTML 5 Programming: Powerful APIs for Richer Internet Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430227907)** (not free).

For the most comprehensive read I recommend the **[HTML5 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)** which goes into all the tiny details.

[Head First HTML5 Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449390544) is by far the best book I have ever seen for newbie front-end developer.

Here is List of Best Books to learn **HTML5**:

- HTML5: Up and Running
- Head First HTML5 Programming
- HTML5 for Masterminds
- Introducing HTML 5
- Dive Into HTML5
- HTML Dog

Another List of **[Top Ten Books about CSS3 / HTML5](http://bzzbeeblog.com/top-10-best-books-about-css3-and-html5/)**